# Does Json Data from ASP.Net Web API returns type of Object out of box

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.Net Web API application which is returning JSON Data,

- Is there a way I can figure out the type of Object(whether its Person Object or Customer   Object) from the JSON data out of the box ?

  Any help will be much appeciated.....

Comment: what do you mean by 'out of the box'?

Comment: I meant whether by default is there any feature present or not....